# Why does getItems method does not suitable for buttons

Tags: java

The javafx class library actually said that the ToolBar.getItems() works for the buttons and nodes, but when I adding buttons into the toolbar, the terminal does not let me compile and saying that it's not suitable.
Here are codes

```
public void setBoard(){
    ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar();//create an empty tool bar
    Button btnnt = new Button ("Next");
    Button btnpr = new Button ("Privieous");
    Button btnst = new Button ("Start");
    Button btnps = new Button ("Pause");
    toolbar.getItems().add(btnnt,btnpr,btnst,btnps);//add all buttons
    border.setBotton(toolbar);//set bottom border
    Label Columnlb = new Label("Enter the weidth");
    Label Rowlb = new Label("Enter the height");
    TextField column = new TextField();
    column.setPreflength(20);
    columns = Integer.parseInt(column.getText());
    TextField row = new TextField();
    rows = Integar.parseInt(row.getText());
    Hbox hbox = new Hbox();
    Hbox.getItems().add(Columnlb,column,Rowlb,row);
    border.setTop(hbox);
}
```

and the error message

```
GOL.java:29: error: no suitable method found for add(Button,Button,Button,Button)
    toolbar.getItems().add(btnnt,btnpr,btnst,btnps);//add all buttons
                      ^
    method Collection.add(Node) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method List.add(Node) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method List.add(int,Node) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

and here is what Library said

```
getItems
public final ObservableList<Node> getItems()
The items contained in the ToolBar. Typical use case for a ToolBar suggest 
that the most common items to place within it are Buttons, ToggleButtons, 
and Separators, but you are not restricted to just these, and can insert 
any Node. The items added must not be null.
```

Comment: Try ´toolbar.getItems().addAll(...)´ if you want to add multiple buttons at the same time.

Comment: I would say it is because the `add` method only supports one entry per method call. So try `toolbar.getItems.addAll(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToolBar.html#getItems--), `getItems()` returns an `ObservableList`, which has `add` method for only one entry as the error says. However, you can use [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addAll-E...-) with your current usage.

Answer (score 0):

`add​(E e)` is inherited from the `List` interface, it receive only one element. Use `addAll​(E... elements)​` instead

```
toolbar.getItems().addAll(btnnt, btnpr, btnst, btnps);
```

`ToolBar​(Node... items)` can also receive the buttons in the constructor

```
ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(btnnt, btnpr, btnst, btnps);
```

Comment: But can't the toolbar use getItems() method? Thank you.